# Going Back without loading images previusly loaded.. Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have my app that loads some images in the first activity, then the user can click one and and new activity is open... the question is:

how can i go back to my first activy without load again all the images?

###################EDIT

i found my problem..

in my first activity i had

```
 @Override
     protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();

         this.finish();
     }
```

when my activity was not visible, then it was finished, thats why my app closed when y click the back button in the second activity.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you find a particular answer helpful, please vote it up. If you find that a particular answer to your question is correct, please accept it.

Comment: r u using listView...?? show some code that you are using to provide most sutaible solution to problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an [onSavedInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method in your first activity. In the method, save the images you want to use to the given bundle. Careful though, if you save too much your application is going to be really slow when switching between activities.